# Isosceles right triangle sides

Tags: geometry, pythagorean-triples

I need to find a reasonable length sides for 3D printing an isosceles right triangle. So basically if the formula goes something like this:

> Right triangle Pythagorus theorem gives us:
>
> x^2 + y^2 = z^2 (z being the hypotenuse)
>
> Since this is an isosceles triangle:
>
> 2 * x^2 = z^2
>
> and z = x * sqrt(2)

My question is how do I find z and x for my needs? And by reasonable I mean:

1. Not very large (in the order of 10s or 100s and maybe even 1000s)
2. Whole numbers or two decimal point precision)

Or is that not a thing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are no solutions with rational $x,z$ to $2x^2=z^2.$ So even using some specific (limited) number of decimals what you look for doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you @coffeemath for the input; I was wondering if I was missing something simple but seems I was not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice approximations come from solutions to [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) $x^2-2y^2=1$ and the closely related $x^2-2y^2=-1$.  We can note that $x=1, y=1$ is a solution to the second.  Because of this solution and [Brahmagupta's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity) if you have a solution $(a,b)$ to one of them, $(a+2b,a+b)$ will be a solution to the other.  Each successive solution will have the ratio of the two numbers a closer approximation to $\sqrt 2$ because the $1$ in the equation is smaller and smaller compared to $x^2,y^2$.  The solutions will also alternate between being above $\sqrt 2$ (when the left side is $1$) and below $\sqrt 2$.  The approximations are $\frac 11=1, \frac 32=1.5, \frac 75=1.4, \frac {17}{12}\approx 1.4167, \frac {41}{29} \approx 1.4138$ and so on.  The last is rather close.

Comment: Ross, wow that works for me! I have a very limited depth of math but I'm fairly ok with fundamentals and logic but I would never have come up with the connections. Thanks much!

Comment: The basic idea is if you can't solve $x^2-2y^2=0$ in the integers, take the next smallest thing available for the right side and see if it works.  You can replace the $2$ by any non-square and the equation is solvable with $1$ on the right.  It may or may not be with $-1$ on the right.  The smallest solution can be rather large.  This is also related to the continued fraction for $\sqrt 2$.  This is an area I have never studied formally, so my knowledge is spotty.